# Russian Doll Cache Digest Partials Not Bubbling Up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, ruby-on-rails-3.2, russian-doll-caching, cache-digests

From my understanding of Russian Doll caching with Cache Digests, in order to prevent us from having to version the fragments,  if I update a child fragment the digest key should bubble up to expire it's parent.

If this is correct I am having an issue where I am updating a child's template that doesn't expire it's parent cache.  In this scenario I am changing the html in /schoolworks/need_grading/row.html.haml and the changes are never reflected because of the cache on /schoolworks/need_grading/row.html.haml.

The haml code for the two different pages are:

```
/schoolworks/need_grading.html.haml
- cache @schoolwork.to_a do
  #other html stuff
  = render partial: 'schoolworks/need_grading/row', collection: @schoolwork

/schoolworks/need_grading/row.html.haml
- cache [ row, get_user_language] do
  #other html stuff
  = link_to row.title
```

I ran rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies TEMPLATE=schoolworks/need_grading and it returned

```
[
  "schoolworks/need_grading/row"
]
```

It looks like the nested dependency matches up with the rendered partial.  I'm lost on why this wouldn't expire the parent cache.